# error handling in for-loop API response with python

Tags: python, for-loop, exception, error-handling, google-analytics-api

Can anyone please help with error handling & for loop in my GA reporting API python script?

What I would like it to do is attempt requesting data from the API an *n* number of times (5 times), if there is an error while pulling the data (generally "Service Unavailable"), log it (*log_progress* function), but keep trying for *n* number of times; eventually, if the number of attempts reaches the maximum amount and the API is still returning an error, run a *send_email* function (which will notify me that some data was not downloaded) and move on with the code to the next item (there is a wider for loop in the script which loops through different GA views/days).

```
for n in range(0, 5):
        try: #GA API request
            api_request = {
                'viewId': viewId,
                'dateRanges': {
                    'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = i),'%Y-%m-%d'),
                    'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = i),'%Y-%m-%d')
                },
                'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'},{'name': 'ga:countryIsoCode'}],
                'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
                "samplingLevel":  "LARGE",                 
                "pageSize": 100000                                          }

            response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
                body={
                    'reportRequests': api_request
                }).execute()

        except HttpError as error:       
           log_progress('errorLog.txt' , error.resp.reason + " - code will try again")
           pass
```

Unfortunately tesing this script is made more complicated by the randomness of GA errors which rarely seem to happen while I'm running the script manually.

Comment: Why did you have a `pass` after `log_progess` in the except block? `pass` is seen as a null statement and ignored by the interpreter. Since you already have code in the `except HttpError as error:` you don’t need a `pass` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing so is by creating a `while` loop and assume failure from the start. Only when the attempt number hits your maximum, you can evoke the `send_email()` module in the `except` block.

```
success = False
max_attempts = 5
attempts = 0

while not success and attempts < max_attempts:
    attempts += 1
    try: #GA API request
        api_request = {
            'viewId': viewId,
            'dateRanges': {
                'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = i),'%Y-%m-%d'),
                'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = i),'%Y-%m-%d')
            },
            'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'},{'name': 'ga:countryIsoCode'}],
            'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
            "samplingLevel":  "LARGE",                 
            "pageSize": 100000                                          }

        response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
            body={
                'reportRequests': api_request
            }).execute()

        success = True

    except HttpError as error:       
        log_progress('errorLog.txt' , error.resp.reason + " - code will try again")
        if attempts == max_attempts:
            sent_email()
```

In this scenario, if there was no success after 5 attempts the program will stop trying and will continue executing the rest of the logic.